# Null pointer dereference with QLabel when using Qt EGLFS

Tags: qt

I have set up Qt to use EGLFS and it works fine for the most part, until I add a QLabel (same for QTextEdit and some other controls). This is my test application:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app {argc, argv};

    QWidget widget {};
    QLabel label {"test", &widget};
    widget.show();

    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

When I run this it seg faults and this is the backtrace:

```
OpenGLContext::handle() const () from /usr/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
QEglFSIntegration::createPlatformOpenGLContext(QOpenGLContext*) const () from /usr/lib/libQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration.so.5
QOpenGLContext::create() () from /usr/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
QEglFSWindow::create() () from /usr/lib/libQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration.so.5
QEglFSIntegration::createPlatformWindow(QWindow*) const () from /usr/lib/libQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration.so.5
QWindowPrivate::create(bool, unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
QWidgetPrivate::create() () from /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
QWidget::create(unsigned int, bool, bool) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
QWidgetPrivate::setVisible(bool) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
```

Seeing this, my assumption is that the QWidget tries to create a QWindow for some unknown reason. This is, according to Qt EGLFS documentation, invalid behaviour, since you cannot mix QWindow and QWidget if running on EGLFS.

I am unsure of how to approach this issue due to my limited knowledge of Qt internals. Could it be a bug in Qt?

Comment: Do other controls work?

Comment: your code has nothing to do wuith open Gl ....

Comment: How do you run your executable?  It's a while since I used `Qt` and EGLFS but I recall you need to specify something like `app-name -platform eglfs` .

Comment: @JarMan Yes, I've only noticed QLabel and QTextEdit cause issues, QTableView, QTabView, different layouts... all work and display correctly.

Comment: @G.M. Yes, at the moment I specify the platform with an argument, as you proposed. This is the only argument, but I do set QT_QPA_ENABLE_TERMINAL_KEYBOARD to 1.

Comment: *"you cannot mix QWindow and QWidget if running on EGLFS."* -- I'm pretty sure there is always a root window. Running on eglfs just means you can't create a second window, like on a desktop environment.